# Calculated Column to Calculate Date

Tags: 2010, calculated-column

I need a column that contains the "Warning Date", which is two weeks prior to the expiry date. I am new to calculated columns so am not quite sure how to go about this.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List and description of date functions you can use in calculated column formula can be found on MSDN:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

In your case, the formula will obviously look like this:

```
=DATE(YEAR([Column1]),MONTH([Column1]),DAY([Column1])-14)
```

There `Column1` should be replaced with the name of your expiry date column.

Also please don't forget to set the calculated field output type to "Date and time".

Answer (score 0):

simply create calculated column with formula as below and output to Date & Time

> =[Column1]+14